# login post activity using Node js Express throws 401 error

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to login through a different domain while my server is present on the another one.My loginmodule.js collects username and password from HTML page below is the code.i am also allowing cors in the code.

```
var name=$('#username').val();
var pass=$('#password').val();
var surl = "http://192.165.2.33:3000/users/login/";
            console.log('link');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: surl,
        crossDomain: true,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify({ username:'name', password:'pass'}),
        dataType: "json", 
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        success: function(responseText,status){
            if(status=='true') console.log('success');

        }
     });
```

This is giving me a 401 unauthorized error. What should be included in my server.js file to avoid the same.   My Server.js file has the follwing code.

```
var allowCrossDomain = function(req, res, next) {
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization, Content-Length, X-Requested-With');

// intercept OPTIONS method
if ('OPTIONS' == req.method) {
  res.send(200);
}
else {
  next();
  }
 };
```

then i have put this on the top

```
app.use(allowCrossDomain);
```

Comment: depends on what is on the route youre posting to

Comment: You should allow **CORS** on your server `crossDomain: true` this won't help you to do cors. Show us your `server.js` code, I assume that you are using **NodeJS**, right?

Comment: Hi I have added , the server.js file for your reference. Please check .

Comment: Try using this module https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors and check the example please. You should `use` cors before your routing

Comment: I don't think that error caused by cross-origin policy (otherwise you'll get specific error in your client js). Please show `/users/login` route handler

Comment: I don't think 401s are caused by CORS. According to https://httpstatuses.com/401, it's more likely due to incorrect HTTP Auth Credentials. Please see onChance's answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're sending this (not the variables, but strings):

```
...
data: JSON.stringify({ username:'name', password:'pass'}),
...
```

But you probably want to send that (the actual content of the html inputs):

```
...
data: JSON.stringify({ username:name, password:pass}),
...
```

So remove the apotrophes and it should work fine!